# How to turn off Bluetooth with j2me

Tags: bluetooth, java-me

To enable Bluetooth shutdown in my software
I tried to operate from this place and could not find
[this](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/bluetooth/jsr082/javax/bluetooth/LocalDevice.html#getLocalDevice())
How to turn off Bluetooth with j2me

Comment: I don't think that's possible with JavaME. When an app needs to use bluetooth, the phone UI usually asks if you want to turn it on. You can't turn on/off bluetooth via JavaME API's.

Answer (score 0):

Since the software does not have access to the cell phone settings for turning off Bluetooth, it is not possible to set it to turn off